# TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata despite BIOS update and intel-microcode package

Tags: debian, kernel, intel, firmware, proxmox

After an kernel update, my proxmox (Debian based) homeserver didn't boot:

[image]

```
# dmesg | grep -i microcode
[    0.080090] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x22 (or later)
[    0.200978] MDS: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode
[    1.043840] microcode: sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x19
[    1.043870] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036877/debian-firmware-bug-tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984970/firmware-bug-tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata-what-should-i-do-about-thi) question to the first `TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata` error. So I updated my [bios](https://de.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z87-GD65-GAMING#down-bios) to the latest version avaliable, which is V1.12 from 05/19/2015. There was no error during the update and it seems to be applied:

```
# dmidecode -t BIOS | grep -E 'Version|Date'
        Version: V1.12
        Release Date: 05/19/2015
```

But the error still occurs. I found out that 5.4.41-1-pve is the latest kernel which boots successfull:

[image]

Older ones like the 5.3 one works too, but no newer versions. So I installed the `intel-microcode` package, which is recommended if there is no BIOS update avaliable to fix the issue. But the problem still persists, I can't boot the newer kernel versions.

#### Regex errors

The other regex errors seems to be caused by `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`. I configured the following filter there:

```
global_filter = [ "r|/dev/zd.*|", "r|/dev/mapper/pve-.*|" "r|/dev/mapper/.*-(vm|base)--[0-9]+--disk--[0-9]+|" "r|/dev/sda" "r|/dev/sdd"]
```

This [avoids standby issues with the disks](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/pvestatd-doesnt-let-hdds-go-to-sleep.29727/), cause proxmox fetches informations from the disks periodically like their usage, which keeps them awake.

I guess that I need to place a delimiter at the end, which means `r|/dev/sda|` instead of `r|/dev/sda` and this was only tolerated in the past, I'm testing this currently.

**EDIT**

I got the same regex error when running `update-grub` and tried to modify the pattern with `|` at the end. After this, `update-grub` run without error. But after rebooting into the new kernel, I got the same error `Invalid filter pattern "r|/dev/sda"` altough I fixed the missing `|` at the end in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`.

When running `apt upgrade`, I get a warning from proxmox that the kernel was updated but is not loaded yet (reboot required). Additionally, it says that it expects microcode revision 0x28 instead of the current active 0.19:

[image]

#### Hardware details

```
# dmidecode -t Baseboard | grep -E 'Manufacturer|Product|Version'
        Manufacturer: MSI
        Product Name: Z87-GD65 GAMING (MS-7845)
        Version: 1.0

# grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4150 CPU @ 3.50GHz

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster

# egrep ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` wasn't reloaded with just calling `update-grub`. [This article](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-vgs-command-reports-error-global-global_filter-unknown/) gave me the right hint (later also [this one in German](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/Intel_Microcode_unter_Linux_aktualisieren)):

> Take a backup of the existing initramfs and rebuild it, so that the changed /etc/lvm/lvm.conf file will be used for subsequent reboots.

To rebuild, I found the [update-initramfs](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/initramfs-tools/update-initramfs.8.en.html) command and executed it like this:

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Since I had multiple kernel versions and expected to may have issues in some (as in my previous tests), I rebuilded all. Normally, it may be enough to rebuild the latest one without `-k all` switch.

Now the server rebooted without any issues and I could verify that the microcode was updated:

```
# dmesg | grep -i microcode
[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x28, date = 2019-11-12
[    0.200700] SRBDS: Mitigation: Microcode
[    0.929176] microcode: sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x28
[    0.929231] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

Previously I had 0x19, now 0x28 as expected from proxmox. It seems that those updates were not applied, until I updated them manually. I guess that this is related to the (now) invalid regex pattern without `|` at the end, which prevents the update from being applied.